# How to access to `this` of d3.js (svg node) in Clojurescript (Reagent)?

Tags: d3.js, svg, clojurescript, reagent

I am using `d3.js` in a `reagent` project, and want to convert the Javascript `d3.select(this)` to ClojureScript. How can I do this?

Here is an example of `d3.select(this)` in `d3.js`:
line 84 of:
http://codepen.io/zyzy5730/pen/JKkWQO?editors=0010

Here is the project and code where I want to add `d3.select(this)` in Clojurescript:
https://github.com/cmal/fcc-voting/blob/master/src/cljs/fcc_voting/views.cljs#L267-L269

I've tried to use `this`, `reagent/current-component`, `(reagent/argv this)` and `(this-as this ...)` . None of them seems to work.

I googled for some examples, they use `d3.js` in `reagent` and use `this`, but `this` in the examples are referring to a reagent component or an argument passed to `(fn...)`, but in `d3.js` when using `.on("mouseover", function(){ d3.select(this)...}`, `this` refers to a svg node on which an event being triggered, maybe a rect or a group or something else.

Thanks.

Comment: When you use `this-as`, have you tried logging the resulting value? I'd expect it to work, and if it's a DOM node, it probably is and the problem is probably elsewhere in your code. The other way I'd go about getting is using the d3.event(https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#event) to get at the DOM event. It's `target` attribute should be the current DOM node.

Comment: Thank you. I've read the source code of `this-as` and tried again, it works.

Comment: I should left `this-as` under the callback `(fn [] (this-as this ....))` so that this could be the target of the event. Can you create an answer for this? Thank you.